# Consume formatted string into three different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code that cuts up a tilte that is formatted like:

> TITLE1 - TITLE2 [XXX]

With the three parts getting "parsed" into an array of three pieces and inserted into three `div` elements:

```
<div class='title'>
<div class='title2'>
<div class='cut'>
```

That code is:

```
var Enumber1 = new Array();

$("#title").each(function(i){
    var text = $(this).text();

    if(text.indexOf('[') != -1 || text.indexOf(']') != -1){
        var Ntext1  = text.split('[')[0];
        Enumber1[i] = text.split('[')[1].split(']')[0];
        $(this).text(Ntext1);
    }
});

$("#cut").each(function(i){         
    $(this).fadeIn("slow");

    if(Enumber1[i] != undefined){
        $(this).text(Enumber1[i]);
    } else {
        $(this).css('N/A');
    }
});
```

So far, I get:

- TITLE1 - TITLE2  >>> stay in div class="title"
- XXX >>>> cut div class"cut"

What I want is to get this text into:

- TITLE1 >>> Stays in `<div class"title">`
- TITLE2 >>> Moves to `<div class"title2">`
- XXX >>> Moves to `<div class"cut">`

So that the final HTML looks like this:

```
<div class='title'>
  TITLE1
</div>

<div class='title2'>
  TITLE2
</div>

<div class='cut'>
  XXX
</div>
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/bro69zvb/6/ for my current code.

Comment: Share also your HTML code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bro69zvb/6/

Comment: This is probably a case for Regex, if the text is consistently formatted with the `-` between Tiles and the `XXX` text always between brackets.

Comment: I tried to edit the question to make it more clear, hopefully I haven't bunged it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a split function at the end of your code:

```js
var Enumber1 = new Array();
          $(".title").each(function(i){
          var text = $(this).text();
          if(text.indexOf('[') != -1 || text.indexOf(']') != -1){
            var Ntext1      = text.split('[')[0];
            Enumber1[i] = text.split('[')[1].split(']')[0];
             $(this).text(Ntext1);
           }
         });
         $(".cut").each(function(i){         
           $(this).fadeIn("slow");
          if(Enumber1[i] != undefined){
            $(this).text(Enumber1[i]);
          }else{
            $(this).css('N/A');
         }
 });
 
// Get the text from <div class="title>
var titleText = $(".title").text();

//TITLE:
  // Get the text before the " - "
  title = titleText.split(" - ")[0];
  // Put the result inside <div class="title">
  $(".title").html(title);

//TITLE2:
  // Get the text after the " - " before the next space
  title2 = titleText.split(" - ")[1].split(" ")[0];
  // Put the result inside <div class="title2">
  $(".title2").html(title2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title">
Tile1 - Tile2 [XXX]
</div>
<div class="title2">
</div>
<div class="cut">
</div>
```

Comment: @Zac No problem! If it worked for you, please accept the answer by clicking the tick. If not, is there still something that doesn't work?

Comment: @Zac what is the output that you recieve? Could you possibly copy and paste it here so I know what's going on?